# react native expo upload image to django api

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework

i am learning react native using the expo cli but i'm stuck trying to upload an image to django rest framework using "expo-image-picker" but i get an error "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."

```
const pick = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
    });


    if (!result.cancelled) {
        setImage(result);
    }
}

const handleSubmit = () => {
    let form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append(image);

    instance({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/API/Create_item",
        data: form_data,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        })
}
```